# Problem with member not disappearing in Azure AD Dynamic Group

Tags: azure, dynamic, rules, membership

I have created a Dynamic Group in Azure AD (not the first time btw). First I created it so it contained about 600 users. I have added an extra rule last friday so that the group would again be empty because nobody in our tenant is compliant with the last rule I added.

However there is 1 user that is still a member of this group. When I use the Validate Preview functionality this user is said to not be compliant with the group rules, but still there he is. This has been longer than 24 hours now. I even updated the rule today to force Azure to re-evaluate the group, but nothing helps.

Here below is the rule. I've modified it a little bit for privacy purposes ofc

```
(user.employeeId -ne null) -and (user.accountEnabled -eq true)
 -and (user.mail -ne null) -and (user.companyName -notin ["value1","value2","value"]) 
 -and (user.extensionAttribute10 -ne "value") -and (user.extensionAttribute8 -eq "True")
```

I tried the microsoft troubleshooting, but in essence it just says to look for syntax errors or to re-evaluate the group by adding a whitespace behind the rule (I've modified it a little so that's essentially the same)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. I changed the value of extensionAttribute10 so that the user would also trigger that rule as not compliant, and after syncing the Azure AD Connect I changed it back. It seems that did the trick.